# Copying a Google Doc with a linked Sheet in it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, google-docs, google-docs-api

I have a Google Doc, within which I linked a Sheet. So, a table and/or a chart, that updates when the corresponding range in the linked spreadsheet updates.

Now, I want to make a copy of this document, so that the copy is linked to a (new) google sheet, which also is a copy of the original google sheet.

My first idea was using the Docs API to update some sort of reference, but it seems it's not possible to update an .. `EmbeddedObject`. I also tried using a Google Apps Script, but there I could also not figure out how to do this. I looked at a few more things, like creating a new doc using the Doc API, but I can't pass the `inlineObjects` or `positionedObjects`<sup>1</sup>, and apparently can't insert it afterwards either.

Did I just miss something? How can I make a duplicate of a Doc and a linked Sheet?

Any tricks, as hacky as they may seem, are very welcome!

<sup>1</sup> While [documents.create](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/create) does accept both in the request body, the reference says "[...]any provided content, are ignored." (and indeed it is)

Comment: Show the code you have so far to copy the Doc and link a new spreadsheet to it.

Comment: *but I can't pass* Quote all the errors in your question. (Though it's highly unlikely you'll get a answer)

Comment: @TheMaster Edited, thanks.
Yeah I almost suspect there's no way of doing this.. Which feels like a huge oversight from Google.

Comment: @anton Consider creating a feature request in the issue tracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details. If you find a similar issue or create a new issue, link it here for wider audience.